# HtmlAgility edit HtmlNode inside foreach

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to replace some nodes inside my root document with some edited HTML but i'm getting an error: `Collection was modified; perhaps enumeration operation is not performed. on parallel foreach`. I know this error occurs because i'm modifying the original structure inside a loop. How could i do it ? Can i use `Parallel.ForEach` or i have to only use a normal `foreach`?

This is my code:

```
Parallel.ForEach( blocks, block =>
{
    var HtmlBlockDoc = new HtmlDocument();

    HtmlBlockDoc.LoadHtml( block.Html );

    var Node = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants().FirstOrDefault( x => x.StreamPosition == block.Order );

    if( Node != null )
        Node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild( HtmlBlockDoc.DocumentNode, Node );
});
```

The block var contains some attributes but the main ones are `Html` that is the html i want to replace on the `HtmlDoc.DocumentNode` and `Order` that is the `StreamPosition that he currently is`. I'm not removing nor adding new nodes, i'm just replacing a `<div></div>` by `<div><p>My Parsed HTML</p></div>` for example. I'm using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) to manipulate the HTML.

I have also tried to clone the `HtmlDoc.DocumentNode` but i got the same error.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to solve this problem using another method to retrieve and replace the desired nodes. If i try to use `HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants()` my search will fail after the first replace because it will change the original structure.

How ? Well, in the `Descendants` method i get all the `Child Nodes` and also their `Grand Childs Nodes` as if they were in the same level, so if i use any position identifier on the first replacement it will work, on the second replacement it won't because i have added more nodes and those nodes will also be added to the list of `Descendants` of the `DocumentNode`.

After discovering that i saw i could use ChildNodes since it will follow the real structure of the three. To do that i will have to get each child, look for my node and:

- If i find it: replace and continue the foreach;
- If i don't find it: get the next child node or get the next sibling and look inside his child for my node

I know i need to use a recursive function to achieve that but i'm having some problems on how to do it. This is my modified code:

```
var HtmlDoc = new HtmlDocument { OptionFixNestedTags = true };
HtmlDoc.LoadHtml( "My HTML" );

foreach( var block in blocks )
{
    var HtmlBlockDoc = new HtmlDocument();

    HtmlBlockDoc.LoadHtml( block.Html.CleanHTML( false ).ReplaceWhiteSpaceTags() );

    ReplaceHtmlNode( HtmlDoc, block );
}

private static List<HtmlNode> ReplaceHtmlNode( HtmlDocument htmlDoc, TemplateBlock block )
{
    var Node = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.ChildNodes.FirstOrDefault( x => x.XPath.Equals( block.XPath ) );

    if( Node != null )
        Node.ParentNode.ReplaceChild( htmlDoc.DocumentNode, Node );
    else
    {
        //How to do it and how to know when to leave ?
        ReplaceHtmlNode(  )
    }
}
```

I posted my original HTML here if anyone wants it to recreate the problem: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/p1unLB9a)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `<p>whatever</p>` adds a new node to the document. And a "normal" `foreach` is going to give you the same error.

Comment: @JimMischel, if i will get the same error with a normal foreach how could i solve this problem ?

Comment: You could always always create a new list for the modified nodes.

Comment: I tried to do it, cloned the root nodes and used them inside the foreach but theyu won't copy the StreamPosition that is what i used to find the node i want to replace. Any ideas ?

Comment: It's no different than any other construct using `foreach`, you're modifying the contents of what is being enumerated in the body of the `foreach` statement. You cannot do that.

Comment: @JeffMercado, i know that but now i have two problems, the one with the list and foreach and the one with the replacement. If i can solve the replacement problem, the other can be solved with cloning since the Clone method from `HtmlAgility` copies the `XPath` from the `Nodes`.